# C++ object tracker

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I created a utility class to keep track of all objects inheriting from it. My main motivation here was to have a clean solution to select which entities in a multiplayer game are synced with the server. I tried to make it as hard as possible to make mistakes (eg. inherit from the wrong crtp parameter) and keep things encapsulated. Well, code speaks more than a thousand words so here we go:

```
#include <unordered_set>    

template<typename t_derived, std::size_t reserved_size = 0>
struct tracker_t
{
    friend t_derived;

private:    // protected:
    tracker_t()
    {
        data::instances().insert(static_cast<t_derived*>(this));

        if constexpr(reserved_size > 0)
        {
            // force initialization of data::s_initialized
            (void)data::s_initialized;
        }
    }

    tracker_t(const tracker_t&)
    {
        data::instances().insert(static_cast<t_derived*>(this));
    }

    ~tracker_t()
    {
        data::instances().erase(static_cast<t_derived*>(this));
    }

    template<typename t_func>
    static void iterate(t_func func)
    {
        for(auto it : data::instances())
        {
            func(it);
        }
    }

    // forward unordered_set methods

    static void reserve(std::size_t n)
    {
        data::instances().reserve(n);
    }

    static bool empty()
    {
        return data::instances().empty();
    }

    static std::size_t size()
    {
        return data::instances().size();
    }

    static auto begin()
    {
        return data::instances().begin();
    }

    static auto end()
    {
        return data::instances().end();
    }

    static auto cbegin()
    {
        return data::instances().cbegin();
    }

    static auto cend()
    {
        return data::instances().cend();
    }

    static typename std::unordered_set<t_derived*>::iterator find(const t_derived* item)
    {
        return data::instances().find(item);
    }

    struct data // private:
    {
        friend tracker_t;

    private:
        static bool reserve()
        {
            instances().reserve(reserved_size);
            return true;
        }

        static std::unordered_set<t_derived*>& instances()
        {
            static std::unordered_set<t_derived*> s_instances;
            return s_instances;
        }

        static const bool s_initialized;
    };
};

// force execution of reserve()
template<typename t_derived, std::size_t reserved_size>
const bool tracker_t<t_derived, reserved_size>::data::s_initialized {tracker_t<t_derived, reserved_size>::data::reserve()};
```

A small example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct animal_t : tracker_t<animal_t>
{
    using tracker_t::iterate;
    using tracker_t::size;

    virtual std::string get_name() const = 0;
};

struct pig_t : animal_t
{
    std::string get_name() const override
    {
        return "Pig";
    }
};

struct duck_t : animal_t
{
    std::string get_name() const override
    {
        return "Duck";
    }
};

struct guinea_pig_t : pig_t
{
    std::string get_name() const override
    {
        return "Guinea Pig";
    }
};


int main()
{
    duck_t duck1, duck2;
    pig_t pig1, pig2;
    guinea_pig_t guinea1;

    std::cout << "Number of objects deriving from animal_t: " << animal_t::size() << "\n\n";

    animal_t::iterate([](animal_t* animal)
    {
        std::cout << animal << ' ' << animal->get_name() << '\n';
    });

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to get some feedback on:

- is there anything broken (ub, performance, ...)
- best practices
- error susceptibility
- code style
- suggestions on how to make it easier to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Creation of the static map

What immediately cought my eye were these lines:

```
    if constexpr(reserved_size > 0)
    {
        // force initialization of data::s_initialized
        (void)data::s_initialized;
    }
```

and of course these:

```
// force execution of reserve()
template<typename t_derived, std::size_t reserved_size>
const bool tracker_t<t_derived, reserved_size>::data::s_initialized {tracker_t<t_derived, reserved_size>::data::reserve()};
```

I get it, but it is a hack. Wouldn't it be better to just create custom set derived from `std::unordered_set` that will handle the `reserve` in its constructor? You won't even need all those `static auto begin()` (that appear to be unused, but I see the commented-out `protected:`).

```
template<typename t_derived, std::size_t reserved_size = 0>
struct tracker_t {
    struct instances_t: protected std::unordered_set<t_derived*> {
        using base = std::unordered_set<t_derived*>;
        using base::reserve;
        using base::insert;
        using base::erase;
        using base::size;
        using base::begin;
        using base::end;
        using base::iterator;
        instances_t() {
            if constexpr (reserved_size > 0)
                reserve(reserved_size);
        }
    };
    static inline instances_t instances;
    tracker_t()                 { instances.insert(static_cast<t_derived*>(this)); }
    tracker_t(const tracker_t&) { instances.insert(static_cast<t_derived*>(this)); }
    ~tracker_t()                { instances.erase(static_cast<t_derived*>(this)); }

    template<typename t_func>
    static void iterate(t_func func) {
        for (auto it : instances)
            func(it);
    }
};
```

If you wonder why I used protected-inheritance (could as well be private) and bunch of `using`'s, then it is because `unordered_set` has public non-virtual destructor ;) Feel free to use composition, if you wish (some prefer it).

And `static inline` is C++17, I believe, more modern way than using the static method returning static local.

Comment: I declare t_derived as friend. As a result it has access to the unordered_set forwards. They aren't meant to be used inside this class. I haven't used static inline variables yet but I'll have a look at them. Inheriting unordered_set would simplify a lot, could catch!